# Vagrant with VMware-Fusion gets connection timeout at `vagrant up` but not `vagrant ssh`

Tags: vagrant, vmware-fusion

I am using Vagrant and VMware-Fusion to build a simple centos 7 vm. The box is custom built with our own private key.

When running `vagrant up --provider=vmware_fusion` I get the error

```
Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

and the job times out (even when I set a very very high timeout with `config.vm.boot_timeout`)

However, I am able to successfully connect to the box with `vagrant ssh`, therefore I assume that my private key file is correct.

I have opened the VMware Fusion GUI and see that the box is just sitting at the login prompt while vagrant is trying to get into it. When there, I am able to manually login with my username and password.

Comment: @kpie, that made no difference

Comment: interesting, I though perhaps you already had a system running so up couldn't start another... Bad guess I guess.